# AttributeError: ‘CCPluginCompile’ object has no attribute android_package

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-3.x

[image]

Unable to run android project on android device . I am using Cocos2d-x 3.9.